# Can you add an outlying value to a max/min attribute? HTML5 Form Validation

Tags: html, validation

I need to add "0" as an allowable value which is outside the max/min range:

```
<input type="number" min="70" max="94" value="0" required>
```

I'm trying to avoid using JavaScript if possible.

Comment: Math topic: if the minimum is 70, 69 and 0 is not allowed.

Comment: I'm aware of that @marcosPerezGude I'm trying to see if there's an exception that I can add to this code to allow for 0 in the instance that the employees using the system are unable to acquire a value.

Comment: If it's required, it means that empty or out of range values are not allowed. If you need it neccessarily you need to write some javascript validation or workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the solution for input of this type is to use the pattern attribute instead of min/max.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern

I don't have the exact regex off the top off my head for your case, but it should be pretty easy. (and I presume yours is only an example anyhow.)

I have a similar issue, where I have number inputs for 0-100 but also need to allow a few values with special meaning like 996-999.